# Set text input in its own scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I am trying to use a data attribute from a input text element to set a default value:

```
$('.fontsizepick').val($("#preview-iframe").contents().find($(this).data('obj')).css('font-size'));
```

The goal is to get the font size from another element and give it as a value to this input text element. There can be many elements.

This does not work. It gives me no error either.

Here is How I did it with a select:

```
$(".fontpick option").filter(function() {
    //may want to use $.trim in here
    return $(this).text() == $("#preview-iframe").contents().find($(this).parent().data('obj')).css('font-family');
}).prop('selected', true);
```

So, I am wondering how I can set a element with a class and give it a value and use its own attributes, basically I want access to the $(this)...

How can I do that?

Comment: Is the iframe on the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function) can accept a function, whose context will be the input element, so you can use `$(this)`.

```
$('.fontsizepick').val(function(){
    return $("#preview-iframe").contents().find($(this).data('obj')).css('font-size');
});
```

From the `.val()` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function):

> A function returning the value to set. *this* is the current element. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old value as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a function, so that `$(this)` will be set to the appropriate element.

```
$('.fontsizepick').val(function() {
    return $("#preview-iframe").contents().find($(this).data('obj')).css('font-size');
});
```